# jQuery append and remove dynamically

Tags: jquery, append

I have this piece of code.
I want to remove the rows created with "Line Add" button with "X" button from each row created.
Any ideas??
Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
     $("#AddLine").click(function () {
        var row = "<tr><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><button>X</button></td></tr>";
        $("#table").append(row);
    });
});
</script>

<button id="AddLine">Add Line</button>
    <table border="1px" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.7+ then you can use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$("#table").on("click", "button", function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
});
```

Note that this assumes the only elements of type `button` you have in your table are used to remove rows. If that's not the case you'll want to probably give the "X" buttons a class and use that in the selector.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/adv7n/) of the above.

If you are not using jQuery 1.7+ you can use the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method instead:

```
$("#table").delegate("button", "click", function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Looking for this. I forgot to move the button selector after .on. Your explanation helped me see the error.

Answer (score 2):

Assign an id to each row, and add a button which removes row with that id on click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowIndex=0;
$(function () {
     $("#AddLine").click(function () {
        rowIndex++;
        var row = "<tr id='row_"+rowIndex+"'><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><button onclick="removeRow('"+rowIndex+"')">X</button></td></tr>";
        $("#table").append(row);
    });
});
function removeRow(index){
    $('#row_'+rowIndex).remove();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.closest("tr").remove();` of jquery

you can try removing last rows of jquery or any specific raw of table as follow

following will remove only last raw

```
$('#table tr:last').remove();
```

following will remove only 2nd raw

```
$('#table tr:eq(1)').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the event click to the X button that you are creating with the same id that the row to identify wich row you want to delete.

Something like:

```
$(function () {
 $("#AddLine").click(function () {
    var row = "<tr id="row_33"><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><input  type=text /></td><td><button id="button_33">X</button></td></tr>";

    $("#table").append(row);

    $("#button_33").click(function () {
          $("#row_33").remove();
    });
});
```

});

You have to add also a process for assign this ids...

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the Live event instead of click.

You could add this instead to your generated html

```
<a class="remove" href="#">X</a>
```

Then you can do

```
$("remove").live("click", function(){
  "find your row. Could be $(this).parents("tr") which searchs your parent until it hits   tr and then remove it by using .remove()"
  return false;
});
```

Live() is used when you have generated stuff and therefor you need to pick that one.
Hope it helps!

Comment: `live` is deprecated and should never be used. If using jQuery 1.7+ the `on` method should be used, and if not, use `delegate` instead.

Comment: oh wasn't aware of that. Does "on" have the same feature as "live" had?

Comment: Yes, as does `delegate`. With `on`, the second argument is a selector. See my answer.

Comment: shrug... this is what I get when I try to contribute :P out of date information and get vote down instead. I typed my answer pretty much at the same time as yours so I didn't see it. Wish I hadn't posted at all now :P

Comment: By the way, I didn't downvote :) Don't let this put you off contributing, everyone makes mistakes! And you learn something new every day!

Comment: I guess. Thanx for the info. As you said, learn something new every day :)